# How to run multiple user X sessions on the same computer, at the same time?

Tags: xorg, users, session

I want to have more than one user logged on **at the same time**, on the **same computer**.

Each user should have a full X session.

It is easy enough to log in to multiple concurrent non-X Linux terminals, but I want the X factor.

Maybe I've missed something, but I only see a Main Menu option to *Log out* of the current user, and nothing for *Switch User*.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean having multiple users use the same keyboard/mouse, or different keyboards/mice? The solutions to those problems are different.

Comment: Just a single keyboard/mouse/monitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Gnome:

Try running `gdmflexiserver`, it will launch a new GDM session. You can switch between them using `Ctrl+Alt+F{8..12}`.

Take note though that logging in with the same user **twice** is a bad idea.

Also, (in Lucid, at least) you can switch users by clicking the Power button in top-right corner and then selecting a user name.
[image]

Comment: Evgeny.. for some reason I don't have that **Switch** option (but it is present in my VM installation of Ubuntu.. I checked just now)...   and checking further... Aha! I see now!.. A couple of months ago, I got rid of the bottom panel entirely, and heavily trimmed the top panel...  and (until today) I did not need the "Indicator Applet Session", so I removed it ...  I had replaced the "Menu Bar" with 
"Main Menu" which showed only "Log off"..  So, problem solved! (it's  all part of the learning curve :( .. gdmflexiserve looks interesting.. and thanks about the warning of double log-on.. Thanks

Comment: I've seen what happens when two X sessions run with the same user (or with sudo): the X authority for the older session gets overwritten. One could use "sudo xhost +local:" as a partial workaround but it still is an issue, gksu in particular doesn't like it.

Comment: Evgeny: Hi I'm trying to find resources enabling me to understand why this: "Take note though that logging in with the same user twice is a bad idea." ? However, your answer is the closest thing I could find on the web regarding this. And I'm unable to understand the consequence of what @Paul Stelian explains in his comment.

Comment: @Atralb Simply put X isn't made to run multiple sessions (multiple logins) at the same time from the same user, because one file is shared but also is normally only owned by one session. The `xhost` command can be used to allow a display (an X server) to accept the current user. BUT for the question in the title, modern Linux distributions support multiple users just fine.

Answer (score 8):

With first X session running login as user you want to use and run in an xterm or at a console prompt:

```
xinit -- :1
```

or

```
startx -- :1
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 16.04

Answer (score 7):

If you want multiple users to use Keyboards/Mouse then that is **multiseatX**.See this [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX)

Comment: Okay, thanks... Today I only have a single keyboard to consider, but your info is good to know...  Ubuntu! It's  got the lot!  :)

Comment: @karthick87 I would like to set a PC with Ubuntu, then start a full graphical session from a laptop while another user is logged in into a different graphical session. It is possible? What tool do I need to set up?