# Startx don't work but lightdm does

Tags: 16.04, xorg

I have a little problem on my Ubuntu, nothing terrible but I still would like to resolve it if it's possible!

I've disabled my GUI at startup to keep my resources, but if I want to start it by the correct way (i.e. `exec startx`) I get a cross-cursor which don't work and no top border on my windows. I still can run commands in the Terminal emulator that run on startup.

To stat my Gui I use the brut method (`exec sudo systemctl start lightdm`) which works but is very dirt as it makes me log twice, <del>and (I think) don't permit to start 2 graphical sessions</del> (Edit finally work,but nevermind).

Initially I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 by I upgraged to Ubuntu 16.04 a month ago.

I don't see any errors in startx's stderr (may be the kernel installation version is not the same that the current one but I don't see how it could be a matter.

```
X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Release Date: 2016-04-04
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux emixam 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic root=UUID=d0a053b8-4a8a-449d-897c-49489421a88e ro quiet splash
Build Date: 22 July 2016  07:50:34AM
xorg-server 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/hadoop/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Aug  9 13:24:48 2016
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
```

So I can survive with this problem, but being a perfectionist, I'd like to solve in order to have a cleaner session...

If someone know how I could solve it would be great!

(BTW, I apologize for my poor English which is obviously not my native language...)

Comment: Doest http://askubuntu.com/questions/221762/how-to-run-2-x-sessions-with-different-display-managers helps you ?

Comment: @iuuuuan It helps me to run several terminals but they all have the issue described above... What i need is to fix my startx

Comment: well I use multiple graphical sessions which include awesome,xfce,kde in my arch linux machine , so its not impossible to do it.

Comment: @KuntalMajumder **I know** there are ways to get around this problem (I currently use them), but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to make *startx* work again.

Answer (score 0):

`startx` will not work in 16.04 because it uses systemd instead and not upstart.

You can go back to upstart, with

```
sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Please note, this will **remove** systemd.

To go back to systemd

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-standard systemd-sysv
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

In short, this is intended behavior and you should start your unity session in 16.04 with `lightdm`.

[Source](https://www.maketecheasier.com/re-enable-upstart-ubuntu/)

Comment: I tried to use upstart-sysv but unexpectably it broke my wifi driver (WTF) and it didn't resolved my issue... So I came back to the standard ubuntu config with the command above, which fortunately worked.
As a debian needed to use Ubuntu for the work I'd have loved to keep my little <del>stupid</del> habits (iceweasel, startx,...). I think I will stay to the defaults just using aliases to avoid to break (again..) my system!

Comment: I don't see how this is accurate. I have the same issue on Ubuntu 16.10 but I run debian on many machines (which also uses systemd) and startx works fine.